# Fetch All Rows, but Place Specific Row on Top of Heap

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a bunch of domains that I store in a table. All of these domains point to the same root directory on the server. Hence each domain displays the exact same website. All of the domains stored in the table will be displayed in a list on the website. I will be looping through the fetched array to construct the HTML.

```
| SLD      | TLD | ... 
+----------+-----+-----+
| example  | com | ... 
| otherone | com | ...
| another  | org | ...
| fourth   | ai  | ...
| ...      | ... | ...
```

What I am going to do is emphasize the domain in the list of domains that corresponds to `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. For instance, if somebody visits example.com, example.com will be emphasized and placed at the top of the list on the page.

[image: image of website]

- Is there a MySQL query that selects all rows, but is able to place one of the rows that matches a condition at index zero of the fetched array?
- If not, other than nested loops, is there a way to select one of the rows or nested arrays whose values correspond to `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` at index zero?

God, I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Order by something = something DESC; but it might be simpler to handle the display order in your application code (e.g. with a bit of JavaScript)

Comment: @Strawberry Handling the order of the domains via JS will detract from the user experience. The list of domains on the website is the main content of the website. The URL that the user is viewing will determine which domain in the database table will be displayed at the top of the page.

Comment: @Strawberry ive uploaded an image to demonstrate what i mean

Comment: I don't see why JS handling will detract from the user experience.

Comment: Anyway, now you have two options

Comment: @Strawberry because JS is client side... if i were to do it with JS, then one of two things would happen: either (1) it would take more time to load the content (since i would have to fetch the data via PHP from the table, then pass the array to JS, then order the array, then display the array) or (2) display the content as soon as possible, then reorder the list in real-time which would be disorientating to the user

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional sort and pass the current site as parameter `@yourSite`

```
 SELECT domain
 FROM YourTable
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN domain = @yourSite 
               THEN 0
               ELSE 1
          END, 
          domain
```

**EDIT** using concat.

```
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN CONCAT (SLD, '.', TLD) = @yourSite 
               THEN 0
               ELSE 1
          END, 
          CONCAT (SLD, '.', TLD)
```

Comment: ive never done something like that before, but i will try it right now. how exactly do i insert a value for `@yourSite`??

Comment: Well that is a different question but check this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54500572/how-to-use-prepared-statements-and-bound-parameters-in-php-oci8. But first you can try it with a constant to make sure work for you

Comment: can i not just write a statement like: `SELECT sld, tld, ask, floor FROM domains ORDER BY CASE WHEN (sld,tld) = @url_host WHERE @url_host = :url_host THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, domain` and then bind the parameter or something like that? or is the only way to bind the value via this `oci_` thing?

Comment: im new when it comes to both PHP and MySQL

Comment: Check edit to see how use `CONCAT`, not sure why you have a `WHERE` there

Comment: If you are new to PHP and MySQL better start with tutorial. Everything I post is very basic. to bind only need to use `:yoursite` i use @yourSite because is how you declare variables in MySql for php binding isnt necesary.

Comment: then can you point me to a tutorial for learning how to bind values to MySQL variables securely?

Comment: because im asking if i can bind a value to the `@yourSite` parameter like that? like can i not insert a `WHERE` clause somewhere into the MySQL statement, something like: `WHERE @yourSite = :url_host` and then bind the desired value to that parameter with something like: `$stmt->bindParam(":url_host", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);`??

Comment: got it working, but is it possible to combine the `SET` and `SELECT` statements?

Comment: @bugwhisperer You would prepare and bind your variables in php- so no need for any SET/@ stuff.

Comment: @Strawberry yah i figured out how to do it three different ways. one way you can set a MySQL variable and execute an additional statement. the other two ways only involve one statement, and one way you bind the value via `bindParam` and the other way you simply bind the value with an array as the parameter for the `execute` statement